# How to prevent ScrollViewer firing ViewChanged event while it is updating?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime

I have two ScrollViewer and I need to sync position of those ScrollViewer when any of the ScrollViewer gets changes, but right now suppose when anyone scrollviewer2 is changed then on calling ChangeView event of ScrollViewer1 it's firing its ViewChangedEvent which is resetting ScrollViewer2 position back.

```
 private void Scroll(ScrollViewer changedScrollViewer)
    {
        var group = ScrollViewers[changedScrollViewer];
        VerticalScrollOffsets[group] = changedScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        HorizontalScrollOffsets[group] = changedScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
        foreach (var scrollViewer in ScrollViewers.Where(s => s.Value == group && s.Key != changedScrollViewer))
        {
            scrollViewer.Key.ViewChanged -= ScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
            if (scrollViewer.Key.VerticalOffset != changedScrollViewer.VerticalOffset)
            {
                scrollViewer.Key.ChangeView(null, changedScrollViewer.VerticalOffset, null, true);
            }

            if (scrollViewer.Key.HorizontalOffset != changedScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset)
            {
                scrollViewer.Key.ChangeView(changedScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, null, null, true);
            }
           //Commenting this line works. But I need to set ViewChange event back.
            scrollViewer.Key.ViewChanged += ScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, the scroll viewer changes view when : 1) user scrolls 2) you call `ChangeView`, you want to sync them when (1) occurs, not (2) . you can use flags to ensure that .

Comment: Thank, some code reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sync two `ScrollViewers`, the better way is make a new `Dependency Property`, and bind it with the same value.  It will notify the `ScrollViewer` to scroll automatically when the `Dependency Property` value changed. This solution will stop `Circular Reference` happening in the ViewChanged event.

I have implemented it for `ListView` in this [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ScroTest.git). You could refer segment code. But for `ScrollViewer`, you need to make `xaml Behavior`, because `ScrollViewer` is sealed class, it could not be inherited.

```
public class SyncBehavior : Behavior<ScrollViewer>
{

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnAssociatedObjectLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += OnAssociatedObjectLayoutUpdated;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnAssociatedObjectLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated -= OnAssociatedObjectLayoutUpdated;
    }

    private void OnAssociatedObjectLayoutUpdated(object sender, object o)
    {
        SyncPointOffSetY();
    }

    private void OnAssociatedObjectLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        SyncPointOffSetY();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnAssociatedObjectLoaded;
    }

    private void SyncPointOffSetY()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject == null) return;

        AssociatedObject.ViewChanged += AssociatedObject_ViewChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var MyScrollViewer = sender as ScrollViewer;
        this.SetValue(PointOffSetYProperty, MyScrollViewer.VerticalOffset);

    }

    public double PointOffSetY
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(PointOffSetYProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PointOffSetYProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointOffSetYProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PointOffSetY", typeof(double), typeof(SyncBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, CallBack));

    private static void CallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var current = d as SyncBehavior;
        var temScrollViewer = current.AssociatedObject;
        if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue & (double)e.NewValue != 0)
        {
            temScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double)e.NewValue);
        }
    }


}
```

**Usage**

```
<ScrollViewer  >
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:SyncBehavior  PointOffSetY="{Binding PointY,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <StackPanel >
        <Rectangle Height="500" Fill="Red"/>
        <Rectangle Height="500" Fill="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Height="500" Fill="Yellow"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" >
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:SyncBehavior  PointOffSetY="{Binding PointY,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <StackPanel >
        <Rectangle Height="500" Fill="Red"/>
        <Rectangle Height="500" Fill="Black"/>
        <Rectangle Height="500" Fill="Yellow"/>
    </StackPanel>

</ScrollViewer>
```

And I have also added the above code to the [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ScroTest.git) that you could refer easily.

Comment: Thanks, But in your sample, you have only VerticalScroll. Things get's trickier when you have both scrolls and want to update accordingly.

Comment: Yep, For horizontalScroll, you could also add `Dependency Property` that used to bind `PointX` value.

Comment: Right. For now I am just checking this `changedScrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0) return;` which works for my given scenario, but will mark this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Nico's solution is much preferable. If you still need something with a flag, it 'll look like this:

```
bool is_programmatic_call = false;
private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (is_programmatic_call)
    {
        is_programmatic_call = false;
        return;
    }
    if(sender == ScrollViewer1)
    {
        ScrollViewer2.ViewChanged -= ScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
        is_programmatic_call = true;
        ScrollViewer2.ChangeView(ScrollViewer1.HorizontalOffset, ScrollViewer1.VerticalOffset, null, true);
        ScrollViewer2.ViewChanged += ScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
    }
    else
    {
        ScrollViewer1.ViewChanged -= ScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
        is_programmatic_call = true;
        ScrollViewer1.ChangeView(ScrollViewer2.HorizontalOffset, ScrollViewer2.VerticalOffset, null, true);
        ScrollViewer1.ViewChanged += ScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
    }
}
```

both the `ScrollViewer`'s `ViewChanged` event is handled by this `ScrollViewer_ViewChanged`

Comment: How about just returning if Horizontal or Vertical Offset is 0 instead of using additional variable?

Comment: Nope, that will make your code uglier and here i didn't 'declare' an extra variable, they are properties of the other ScrollViewer

Comment: I mean you added extra variable `is_programmatic_call` to check for programmatic call, isn't it better to just use whether HorizontalOffset or VerticalOffset is 0?

Comment: Most probably you have misunderstood the meaning of `HorizontalOffset` and `VerticalOffset`. Those having a value of zero has nothing to do with whether the ScrollViewer has changed it's view or not - programmatically or by user.